# What is faster? SQL database read/write or file read/write?

Tags: java, database, performance, file, load-testing

I am implementing a load testing tool in java. I want to store load test results temporally to match them with the expected results at the end. I cannot match responses while running the load test as it will affect the load test speed.

So I want to store the results in a minimal writing time. What is the best possible way to store data? Write to a local database or write to local hdd as files?

Note: Results cannot be kept in the RAM as results may be large several gigs.

Comment: I think it is far too general. For example a database can be implemented in a local file and also in memoery database.

Comment: If you have a complex record that needs to be stored at the same time with better security then use Database. If you are only storing configurations and does not worry so much on privacy then a file can be handy. BTW even if you 128 GB of RAM that cant store a permanent data.

Comment: No consideration about security. My only consideration is performance. @Enzokie Anyway I'm not storing a configuration. I store the results obtain from the load test.

Comment: Buffered, asynchronous sequential write to file will be the fastest out-of-memory storage of accumulated data.

Comment: @dra I haven't compared the speed but I think its File.

Comment: If your result can't be kept in RAM, then a local database is a file on your local hdd isn't it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With load testing, usual approach would be to have multiple agents putting load on the system. Then there would need to be some benchmark on system and on agents. Usually load will be split so one agent can keep own statistics. When test is finished you can aggregate agents statistics kind of "off line" and cross compare it with benchmark on system side.

Answering your question about I/O write speed: it depends on many different factors so you would need to benchmark both scenarios. However considering fact that database needs to support transactions, indexing and store data my blind guess would be that in your use case file and raw data would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

File is more efficient than DB. DB is a software based on file system but if you implement your solution by file effectively it would be more rapid and does not have the overload of Db.
Also in DB if you use ORM (JPA) it makes the code more slower than pure JDBC. It's obvious that more convenience in data handling (file->JDBC->JPA) results more time consuming.

I suggest you to use file manipulation for this purpose and use some more fast technology like nio (New IO) in java.